# Help me out with my sloppy HTML/PHP

Tags: php

This might sound like a silly question but how would I make this code seem...neater?

```
    echo "<h3><font face='helvetica'><font size='4'><b><font color='B80000'>$title</font></font></font></b> <font color='A0A0A0'>$category &nbsp;</font><font color='A0A0A0'><a href='profile.php?id=$userid'>$user</a></font>
    <font face='helvetica'><font size='3'><br>&nbsp;$desc</font></font><br>

       <h3><font color='101010'> &nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;$zip&nbsp;<font color='A0A0A0'>$date</font>  </font></h3>";
?>
```

There's nothing wrong with the code but it looks so sloppy - I was wondering if someone could help me out with making it look neat and tidy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Don't use `<font>` - move those rules to CSS, where you can style the `<h3>` element. **Also!** Not all computers have Helvetica, so you may want to change that to `"Helvetica", Arial;` so the design stays somewhat inline with your intent.
2. Stay away from using `<h3>` twice - put the second h3 into a `<p>` or something similar, and use CSS to style that.
3. `&nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;$zip&nbsp;` is dirty - concatenate the string with spaces in PHP, then echo the string.
4. Instead of using echo to output the PHP, just use `echo` inside of the HTML for the certain elements - this will make it much more readable.
5. Use `htmlspecialchars()` on every piece of data that comes out of a database *before* you echo it to the page. This prevents invalid HTML *and* XSS vulnerabilities.

That should tighten it up!

Comment: Thanks! I would accept the answer right now but it told me to wait a couple mins:P

Comment: @melee: I took the liberty to add #5 - something that 95% of all PHP developers tend to forget.

Comment: @Mariee McCullin you should take a look at some open source PHP projects to see how they're doing it - that should give you an idea of the _style_ that developers tend to use. Next time you're designing something, it'll give you a better perspective from the outset.

Answer (score 3):

Learn about [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) [for PHP](http://www.tonymarston.net/php-mysql/model-view-controller.html).

Learn about [frameworks](http://codeigniter.com) [for](http://cakephp.org) [php](http://www.phpframeworks.com/). Start using one.

Or start by separating CSS from other data. Use PHP to output dynamic data, use HTML/CSS for static data. Avoid mixing the two.

Links from google

Answer (score 0):

move all `<font ....>` codes to `style=""` attribute

also consider moving html out of php echo, i.e.

```
<h3>
<a href="<?php echo ... ?>"><?php echo ... ?></a>
</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've put it into heredoc for you, but most of the changes you'll need to do yourself.

```
    // use heredoc's: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
    $out = <<HER 
    <h3><!-- you should use CSS to do this. You should get rid of font tags -->
        <font face='helvetica'> <!-- you don't need three either, you can put them all in one -->
            <font size='4'>
                <b>
                    <font color='B80000'>
                        $title
                    </font>
                </font>
            </font>
        </b><!-- move this so that it matches above -->

        <font color='A0A0A0'>
            $category &nbsp;
        </font>
        <font color='A0A0A0'>
            <a href='profile.php?id=$userid'>
                $user
            </a>
        </font>
        <font face='helvetica'>
            <font size='3'>
                <br> <!-- make this self closing -->
                &nbsp;$desc
            </font>
        </font>
        <br>
        <h3><!-- nested??!? You're already in H3-->
            <font color='101010'>
                &nbsp;$city,$state&nbsp;$zip&nbsp;
                <font color='A0A0A0'>
                    $date
                </font>  
            </font>
        </h3>
HER;

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The very first thing you can do is close the PHP tag, write out your HTML while leaving spaces and newlines and indenting as you open tags, and re-open PHP when you need it:

```
?>
<h3>
    <font face='helvetica'>
        <font size='4'>
            <b>
               <font color='B80000'><?php echo $title; ?></font>
        (...)
            </b>
        </font>
    </font>
</h3>
<?php
```

Also look into the [heredoc syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

On a non-syntactical sidenote you would be better served in the long run by using CSS instead of all those `<font>` tags:

```
<style type="text/css">

.myTitle {
    font-face: helvetica;
    font-size: large;
    color: #B80000;
}

</style>

echo "<h3 class='myTitle'>$title</h3>" ;
```